# File `subscript.sty' not found. \usepackage

Tags: miktex

I recently wanted to start writing thesis. However I got this error. I installed the "fragments" name folder from miktex since the subscript.sty was not available in miktex. Searching sources I got that, I should create new folder 'Subscript' in your MiKTeX installation folder (e.g.
`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`) and put the folder there. then reconfigure lyx to solve the problem.

I think the problem is with lyx I am not sure. Lyx reconfiguration takes too much time stucked in "checking for package tcolorbox [tcolorbox]" Does anybody have any idea? Shouldit be solved like this? Reconfiguration is failed. default texclass is used but lyx may not be able to work properly. (I AM NOT SURE THE PROBLEM IS WITH LYX!)

By the way after putting subscript in that folder I again could not see it in the miktex console.Is it like that?

Now I checked and I remove the usepackage for subscript.This time tabu.sty is not found.I updated miktex. why I got these errors? I cannot install allof them manually!

My miktex is 2.9 and lyx is 2.3.

P.S.Overleaf is really good but it is filtered in this sh ... t country I cannot use it!

Comment: Have you got an example piece of code? so people can try and compile it to help you out.

Comment: Due to the fact that it has many folders and it is not a simple code I could not share it here.

Comment: Without seeing an example its hard to tell but last time I had this error I ran the file through a SageMath terminal, then ran the sage file twice in a terminal which produced a .sty file, not sure if this is the best way to do it but it worked for me. But again, without any of your code its hard to tell if its for the same reason you are having.

Comment: You are right. lets see how can I figure out